# Flutter Bloc Unit Test return an empty array

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, bloc, bloc-test

I'm trying to make a unit test using the bloc_test library.

Here are my codes.

**Login Cubit**

```
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LoginState> with HydratedMixin {
  final UserRepository _userRepository;
  LoginCubit(this._userRepository) : super(LoginInitial());

  Future<void> login (String email, String password , bool remember) async {
    bool result = await _userRepository.isLoginCorrectWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    if (result){
      emit(LoggedIn(remember: remember, email: email));
    } else {
      emit(LoginError());
    }
  }
}
```

**Login States**

```
part of 'login_cubit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class LoginState extends Equatable {}

class LoginInitial extends LoginState {
  final bool remember;
  final String email;
  LoginInitial({this.remember = false, this.email = ''});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [remember, email];
}

class LoggedIn extends LoginState {
  final bool remember;
  final String email;
  LoggedIn({required this.remember, required this.email});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [remember, email];
}

class LoginError extends LoginState {
  LoginError();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
class MockUserRepository extends Mock implements UserRepository {
  @override
  Future<bool> isLoginCorrectWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) {
    return Future.value(true);
  }
}

void main() {
  group('LoginCubit', () {
    late LoginCubit loginCubit;

    setUp(() {
      loginCubit = LoginCubit(MockUserRepository());
    });

    tearDown(() {
      loginCubit.close();
    });

    test('the initial state value is LoginInitial', () {
      expect(loginCubit.state, LoginInitial());
    });

    blocTest<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
      'TODO: description',
      build: () => loginCubit,
      act: (cubit) => cubit.login("any email", "any password", true),
      expect: () => <LoginState>[
        LoggedIn(remember: true, email: "any email"),
      ],
    );
  });
}
```

My issue is that the second test return always an empty array.
With some prints, I'm sure that the code is emitting the LoggedIn states but the test actually don't recognize it.

Where did I make a mistake ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using an Hydrated Bloc without initializing it in the test.
Here's the solution to it :
https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2022#issuecomment-747918417

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the stub for the repository function call.

1. Create an Object from the Mock Class `MockUserRepository repo = MockUserRepository();`
2. Pass this object to the `LoginCubit` in the `setUp` function like this

   `setUp(() { loginCubit = LoginCubit(repo); });`
3. Add this line to the `act` function in the test

   ```
       when(repo.isLoginCorrectWithEmailAndPassword(any, any)).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
   ```

so the whole test should be like this

```
blocTest<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
  'TODO: description',
  build: () => loginCubit,
  act: (cubit) {
      when(repo.isLoginCorrectWithEmailAndPassword(any, any)).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
      cubit.login("any email", "any password", true);
  },
  expect: () => <LoginState>[
    LoggedIn(remember: true, email: "any email"),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, unfortunally, it didn't help to run the test correctly. I still got an empty array at the end.
The `when.thenAnswer` isn't the same as overriding the MockUserRepository class like I did before ?